# Why did Biff not pursue a relationship with Lorraine in the original timeline?

Tags: character-motivation, back-to-the-future

It seems pretty clear to me that Biff was maniacally obsessed with Lorraine, even in the original timeline, and not the kind of guy who takes "no" for an answer.

We know that Biff eventually gave up on her, and she marries George. Still, it seems out of character to me that Biff would have simply left them alone to fall in love at the dance in the original timeline, given there was nothing George would have done to stop him.

I'm assuming that:

1. George and Lorraine still "parked" like she did with Marty in the original timeline, giving Biff the opportunity.
2. Biff in fact did leave them alone in the original timeline, as I find it unlikely Lorraine would have still fallen in love with George that night if he hadn't.

Is there any supplementary information indicating why Biff would have simply left them alone?

Comment: I'll be honest, I always assumed that (off camera), Biff did assault Lorraine and perhaps persistently cuckolded George.  This is a big part of why Lorraine was such a shell of a woman in the original timeline.  Marty is our main point of view, and let's be honest there's no way you tell your kids what happened on prom. George and Lorraine could still have stayed together from the shared trauma if nothing else. I have no facts,so this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I originally had the same thought, but she definitely seems to look back on that night very fondly when recounting it to her kids, even in the original timeline. So I consider anything with Biff happening in the original timeline unlikely.

Comment: The assumption that George and Lorraine would still have "parked" is rather questionable, since Marty has to do quite a lot of work to convince George to do that.

Comment: @Paul ...that IS an answer. It doesn't ask for clarification, it (tries to) answer the question. And I, for one, think that it would make a good answer! Write it up and you will have my +1 :)

Comment: @xDaizu Thanks, but it's not an answer because it lacks evidence.  It's just my opinion and speculation.  As Tronman says, it's just as likely I'm wrong.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear; Biff rapes Lorraine (and makes her pregnant with Dave) while they're "parked". He then moves on for the night, she's traumatized and George shows up. She is afraid she might be pregnant so she marries George and pretends Dave is his son.

Comment: I tweaked the title some, because Biff doesn't "leave them alone" (Biff is still bullying George in the original 1985)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Biff's actions at the dance in *Back to the Future* were significantly affected by Marty's presence in 1955.  Being repeatedly humiliated, including having $300 worth of damage done to his car when it was filled with manure, left him really, really angry.  Presumably, it was because of his particularly nasty attitude that night that he ultimately assaulted Lorraine.  And remember, he didn't show up at the parked car looking exclusively or even primarily for Lorraine; he was mostly there to get Marty.  Lorraine happened to be there, and moreover, raping Lorraine would have been, in Biff's mind, a further blow to Marty; Biff felt that *he* was getting *Marty's* girl.

In the original timeline Biff certainly had the hots for Lorraine, at least initially.  But without the events with Marty, he would not have been nearly as aggressive in an attempt to woo her.  There would be no particular reason for him to go after her specifically at the Enchantment Under the Sea dance.  And after the dance, she would be George's girlfriend.  Biff would not get a thrill out of stealing George's girl; George was so pathetic that Biff might be turned off a girl who had fallen for George and made out with George.

In the alternate timeline in the second movie, Biff holds a grudge against George and still wants Lorraine.  But that is part of the revised timeline, in which George had laid him out with a single punch back in 1955.  Vengeance for that (and whatever other perceived humiliations a much stronger George had inflicted on Biff in the intervening years), along with Biff's vast wealth in the alternate timeline, were responsible for Biff murdering George in that world.

Comment: That's a great answer. One thing still bothers me though - in BTTF2, we see the exchange between Biff and Lorraine when she buys her dress. In that scene, he seems particularly obsessed with having Lorraine, having absolutely nothing to do with Marty, as he didn't even know they were going to the dance together at that point. I get the exchange probably didn't happen in the original timeline, since Biff was there picking up his car that Marty damaged. But it still shows that he was obsessed with her on a level unrelated to just getting back at Marty.

Comment: @Tronman actually, that scene proves that he mainly shows interest when she happens to cross his way, but he quickly gives up, when he is not already in an angry mood or drunk or both. Biff is not a rapist in the first place. So in the original timeline, it might be just a matter of not crossing their ways under such circumstances. Given the introverted George of the original timeline, Lorraine and George would not show up on many parties where they could cross Biff’s way.

Comment: @Holger True. Come to think of it, Biff doesn't really get upset until Lorraine specifically mentions "Calvin Klein". So perhaps if she had said she was going with George, he would have had an attitude more like "Fine. You two losers deserve each other."

Answer (score 12):

In the original timeline, Lorraine fell in love with George well before the dance: when her father knocked him down with his car. Then, when Marty showed up, he saved his father from being hit by the car, got hit instead, and Lorraine started falling in love with him instead.

Comment: What does this have to do with Biff's actions at the dance?  When Lorraine fell for *a boy* didn't change, just which boy she fell for.  It's what *else* changed that form the basis for this question.

Comment: Also, if we equate "falling in love with someone" with "wanting to spend the rest of your life" with said person, the dialog makes it clear that Lorraine didn't fall in love with George until he kissed her on the dancefloor.

Answer (score 8):

There's no evidence that Lorraine and George "parked" as she and Marty did (indeed it was Marty's suggestion since he had the plan for George to save Lorraine form him.)

Biff's attack on Lorraine was more a crime of opportunity - he was drunk when he came across them. It's likely that in the original timeline, George and Lorraine simply went into the dance, and Biff would never have tried anything like that with all the people watching.

BTW Biff's resulting character in the new timeline also gives us a bit of insight into his personality, it seems there's a touch of cowardice in that he acts tougher than perhaps he is. Remember, after George laid him out just once, Biff did not come back at him the next day or anything to reassert his authority - he was certainly physically strong enough if he'd had the guts - he either left George alone or backed down whenever the newly confident George stood up to him - we can see this because George is the dominant one in that particular relationship by 1985.

So it's quite probable that *Lorraine* stood up to Biff in the original timeline and may have in fact protected George (esp. considering how she fell in love with him) - maybe not physically, but assertively enough to get Biff to back down rather than risk further humiliation, instead settling for someone more in his own league. Remember, Lorraine was confident all along in either timeline.

Comment: *"it seems there's a touch of cowardice in that he acts tougher than perhaps he is"* - as is usually the case with bullies. And indeed, often (though not always), standing up to them once will make them leave you alone in future.

Comment: My assumption was based on Lorraine's statement that this isn't the first time she "parked", and that in the original timeline, it may have been her idea. Although that would contradict her statement that George kissed her for the first time on the dancefloor - but I could also see Lorraine simply omitting those details to her kids, especially given her attitude towards her daughter

Answer (score 0):

He did pursue her. At the start of the first movie, before any time travel, Biff says to Marty, "Say hi to your Mom for me." To me that says that he had an affair with her at some stage, perhaps more than once. But Lorraine was still in love with George (due to the Florence Nightingale effect) so she always went back to him.

As for the dance, Biff and his mates were hanging around outside looking for trouble, so Biff probably wasn't even inside when George and Lorraine kissed.

I don't agree that Biff's interactions with Marty changed his attitude to Lorraine significantly. He asks her to the dance before he's heard she's going with "Calvin Klein".